# Ajax code control

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

Sorry for that stupid question but, is this code right because it seems to be broken.

```
var request_type; 
var browser = navigator.appName;
if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
    request_type = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}else{
    request_type = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
return request_type;
}

var http = createObject();

var nocache = 0;
function vloz() {

var kom= encodeURI(document.getElementById('komen').value);
var site_name = encodeURI(document.getElementById('user_id').value);
var p_id = encodeURI(document.getElementById('p_id').value);
var zed = encodeURI(document.getElementById('zed').value);

nocache = Math.random();
http.open('get', 'kmnt.php?site_url='+kom+'&site_name=' +site_name+'&site='+p_id+'&    zed='+zed+'&nocache = '+nocache);
http.onreadystatechange = insertReply;
http.send(null);
}
function insertReply() {
    if(http.readyState == 4){
    }
}
```

I have a form when i am sending komen, user_id, p_id and zed

Comment: What kind of error do you see?

Comment: @AllenLiu I cant see no error, im just starting with Ajax.. But, inside of kmnt.php is mysql INSERT query i a can see that query wasnt inserted

Comment: I would recommend using FireBug/FireFox so that you can get the error message (if there is one) from your JavaScript. http://getfirebug.com/javascript

Comment: $Allen Liu /kmnt.php?site_url=aaa&zed=undefined&site_name=4&site=4&nocache=0.2857547387611278 (final url)
Javascript is failing on var zed... bud i dont know why..

Comment: If that is the case, looks like there is something wrong with your form. Can you post the HTML snippet for your form?

Comment: @AllenLiu form is ok.. now it is working, but, for understanding, i have something like fb wall.. but i can send comment to just first status from mysql query.. if its gonna be second, its not even send data to mysql query...

Comment: I apologize but I don't quite understand what it is you are trying to do. Do you have a url you can give to me?

Comment: @AllenLiu Yes but you must login, if its not problem so: [Login](http://test-income.mzf.cz/login.php) email = test password = test .. then go to [Profile - problem location](http://test-income.mzf.cz/profil.php?id=4)

Comment: Hmmm...there seems to be a lot of issues.  The first window does a double post but it works somehow.  The other chat windows do a single post but the update in the UI is not working.  I think this is way out of the scope of the help that I can provide.  I'm sorry.

Comment: @AllenLiu uh, thats ok, seriously, i have no idea, why it is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is it but it appears that you have one too many curly braces in the beginning of your code:

```
if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    request_type = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} else {
    request_type = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
return request_type;

// }   <- extra one here
```